# Variable Indefinida en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo un proyecto en laravel donde la ruta principal es layouts.admin, bueno en admin.blade.php estoy cargando datos de películas como si fuera un index.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

web.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca esta el admin.blade.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca esta el motodo show que carga los datos de la pelicula

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me sale el siguiente error en admin.blade.php cuando doy click en una pelicula para poder ver sus detalles (pelicula.show). El error es del index de AdminController donde cargo los datos pero solo me sale el error cuando doy click en la pelicula. Por que cuando estoy en el admin me muestra normalmente los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y el error completo que te muestra finalmente cuál es?

Comment: No se ve el error que muestra

Comment: Ahi muestro el error, lo siento no se cargo. y muchas gracias